# Verifying definitions: Are these subvariants of “absoluteness of ...” commonly defined in this way (set theory)?

Tags: set-theory, definition

Let the relativisation of a ZF formula $\varphi$ to a class $M$ (with $\in$) be denoted as $\varphi^M$. This is simply the original formula $\varphi$ but with quantifiers replaced with $M$-bounded counterparts.

For possible reference, here is one definition I do *not* have doubts about as it defined concisely in different sources:

> **Definition** (absoluteness of a formula $\varphi$)**.** A formula $\varphi = \varphi(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ is *absolute (**as a formula**) wrt* $M$ if
> $$\forall x_1,\dotsc, x_n \in M\quad \varphi^M(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \Leftrightarrow \varphi(x_1, \dotsc, x_n).$$
> The $\Rightarrow$-direction is *upward absoluteness*, and $\Leftarrow$-direction is *downward absoluteness*.

- ***Q:*** Are the following four definitions correct, i.e., is this how these concepts are commonly (implicitly) defined?

> **Definition 1** (absoluteness of a class $C$)**.** A class $C$ (with defining formula $\phi = \phi(x)$) is  *absolute **as a class** wrt* $M$ if
> $$\forall x\in M \quad \phi^M(x) \Leftrightarrow \phi(x).$$
> (So this is simply absoluteness of $\phi$).
> By writing $C^M = \{x \in M \mid \phi^M(x)\}$, we may also write this condition as $C^M = C \cap M$.

> **Definition 2** (absoluteness of a relation $R$)**.** A relation $R$ (with defining formula $\psi = \psi(x,y)$) is *absolute **as a relation** wrt* $M$ if
> $$\forall x,y\in M\quad \psi^M(x, y) \Leftrightarrow \psi(x, y).$$
> (So this is just absoluteness of $\psi$). By writing $R^M = \{(x,y) \mid (x, y) \in M \times M \wedge \psi^M(x, y) \}$, we may also write this condition as $R^M = R\cap (M\times M)$.

> **Definition 3** (absoluteness of a function $F$)**.** A function $F$ (with defining formula $\chi = \chi(x,y)$) is *absolute **as a function** wrt* $M$ if
> \begin{align*} \forall& x \in M\, \exists ! y \in M \quad \chi^M(x,y) \wedge \phantom{}\\
> \phantom{}\wedge \forall& x, y \in M\quad \chi^M(x,y) \Leftrightarrow \chi(x, y).
> \end{align*}
> (So the second half of the main conjunction is simply absoluteness of $F$ as a relation).
> By writing $F^M = \{(x,y) \mid \chi^M(x,y)\wedge x \in M \times M\}$, we may also write this condition as $F^M = F|_M$ where $F|_M$ is the restriction of $F$ to $M$.

> **Definition 4** (absoluteness of a constant $c$)**.** A constant $c$ (with defining formula $\xi = \xi(x)$) is *absolute **as a constant** wrt* $M$ if
> $$\exists! x \in M \quad \xi(x).$$
> This is the same as saying $c \in M$. This definition should be equivalent to stating
> $$(\exists! x \in M \ \ \xi^M(x)) \wedge \xi^M(y) \Rightarrow \xi(y).$$
> If we define $c^M$ to be the unique element of $M$ such that $\xi^M(x)$, we can also write the condition as $c^M = c$.

---

These definitions are an amalgamation of information from various sources, and do not appear (as far I can tell) exactly in this complete form in any of them. I am working on Weaver's *Forcing for mathematicians* where most of the concepts are used but not strictly defined. I also have access to Jech's 5th edition (defining some of these but not all and not exactly in this form), and older Kunen (similar). Question also motivated by [Noah Schweber](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28111/noah-schweber)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987197/questions-about-absoluteness-set-theory/3987202#3987202) and an article, doi: [10.1016/S0079-8169(08)61193-9](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0079-8169(08)61193-9).

I am self-studying the material. This question is intended to check whether or not my understanding is correct.